# When should I really set "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" to "true" in my response headers?

Tags: http, cors, httpresponse, same-origin-policy, fetch-api

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Credentials) says, when the credentials like cookies, authorisation header or TLS client certificates has to be exchanged between sites `Access-Control-Allow-Crendentials` has to be set to `true`.

Consider two sites A - https://example1.xyz.com and another one is B- https://example2.xyz.com. Now I have to make a http `Get` request from A to B. When I request B from A I am getting,

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://example1.xyz.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access."

So, I'm adding the following response headers in B

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("origin"));
```

This resolves the same origin error and I'm able to request to B. When and why should I set

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
```

When I googled to resolve this `same-origin` error, most of them recommended using both headers. I'm not clear about using the second one `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`.

1. When should I use both?
2. Why should I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `origin` obtained from request header rather than wildcard `*`?

Please quote me an example to understand it better.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Allow-Credentials would be needed if you want the request to also be able to send cookies. If you needed to authorize the incoming request, based off a session ID cookie would be a common reason.

Setting a wildcard allows any site to make requests to your endpoint. Setting allow to origin is common if the request matches a whitelist you've defined. Some browsers will cache the allow response, and if you requested the same content from another domain as well, this could cause the request to be denied.

Comment: Neatly explained @clint... `Some browsers will cache the allow response` means - when the the browser requests again - the preflight request will not be sent from the browser right? It would directly get the response skipping initial request rit? Am I understanding it in a right way?

Comment: Thanks, exactly - the OPTIONS request wouldn't be sent if it were cached. You could set a query string param to version the hostname,?hostname=... or a common practice is the current unix timestamp. That is assuming you are sending back a specifically allowed origin.

Comment: I couldn't get you here @clint.. I have seen using timestamps in request when I'm accessing from the same domain like - when I am requesting like `https://example1.xyz.com?fileid=123` - the browser would cache its response. So, when I invoke the same request from the client - the response would be fetched from browser cache rather than sending it to the server. So, we would append timestamp to the request like `https://example1.xyz.com?fileid=123&&_t=123456` - which we would add request to identify it as unique request

Comment: i.e.; to say the browser that it is not the same as the one which you have invoked previously - so, the request would be sent to server rather than fetching it from browser cache..

Comment: But I'm not sure what info would be cached here with this "OPTIONS" request..... I'm not clear with this @clint `That is assuming you are sending back a specifically allowed origin` - please explain me a bit more..

Comment: Also, `if you requested the same content from another domain as well, this could cause the request to be denied.` - Does this mean when I request from B(https://example2.xyz.com) to A like `https://example1.xyz.com?fileid=123` - A supports CORS. So, When A sets `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` to `true` - the options request would be cached. When B sends request like `https://example3.xyz.com?fileid=123` to another domain with same query param - this request would get blocked right?

Answer (score 7):

Setting `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` actually has two effects:

- Causes the browser [to actually allow your frontend JavaScript code to access the response](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-access-control-allow-credentials) if credentials are included
- Causes any `Set-Cookie` response header [to actually have the effect of setting a cookie](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#example-cors-with-credentials) (the `Set-Cookie` response header is otherwise ignored)

Those effects combine with the effect that setting [`XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) or [`credentials: 'include'`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Sending_a_request_with_credentials_included) (Fetch API) have of causing [credentials (HTTP cookies, TLS client certificates, and authentication entries)](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#credentials) to actually be included as part of the request.

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#example-cors-with-credentials has a good example.

Comment: TLS/SSL client certificates an old, rarely-used mechanism intended to provide for both completely password-less sign-in and also a kind of two-factor authentication. There’s good-but-old writeup at https://blog.pilif.me/2008/05/26/why-is-nobody-using-ssl-client-certificates/ and a related more-recent discussion at https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=6026102

Answer (score 3):

> Why should I set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `origin` obtained from request header rather than wildcard `*`?

You shouldn’t unless you’re very certain what you’re doing.

It’s actually safe to do if:

1. The resource for which you’re setting the response headers that way is a public site or API endpoint intended to be accessible by everyone, and
2. You’re just not setting cookies that could enable an attacker to get access to sensitive information or confidential data.

For example, if your server code is just setting cookies just for the purpose of saving application state or session state as a convenience to your users, then there’s no risk in taking the value of the `Origin` request header and reflecting/echoing it back in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value while also sending the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` response header.

On the other hand, if the cookies you’re setting expose sensitive information or confidential data, then unless you’re really certain you have things otherwise locked down (somehow…) you really want to avoid reflecting the `Origin` back in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` value (without checking it on the server side) while also sending `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

If you do that, you’re potentially exposing sensitive information or confidential data in way that could allow malicious attackers to get to it. For an explanation of the risks, read the following:

- https://web-in-security.blogspot.jp/2017/07/cors-misconfigurations-on-large-scale.html
- http://blog.portswigger.net/2016/10/exploiting-cors-misconfigurations-for.html

And if the resource you’re sending the CORS headers for is *not* a public site or API endpoint intended to be accessible by everyone but is instead inside an intranet or otherwise behind some IP-address-restricted firewall, then you definitely really want to avoid combining `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-reflects-`Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`. (In the intranet case you almost always want to only be allowing specific hardcoded/whitelisted origins.)

Comment: It's also safe if you don't include `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`. That's the real dangerous header.